# How to make a secondary Pages Screen

Tags: pages, admin

I want to make a custom Pages Screen in admin, leaving `edit.php?post_type=page` as it is. This screen will have different columns, different filters etc. I want the link for it to go under Pages and Posts, let's say it's called "Pages - alt" What's the best way to go about this? Should I just make the page from scratch as an admin page or is there a way to leverage `WP_Posts_List_Table` so I don't have to start from scratch?

Where would be a good place to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll start with [`add_menu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/), to create the actual admin page. From there, it's really up to you, but I recommend using the `WP_Posts_List_Table`: nearly everything is built-in and ready to use.

There are several comprehensive articles on creating a custom list table; most of them should be sufficient for getting you started.

Comment: Thanks I'm off to a good start now.